# Cant change font face in Sketch

Tags: sketchapp

I've been using Sketch for years now and of course I love it. Recently tho I've come across a strange bug. When I have a font layer selected I can't change the font face. It doesn't matter what font I have selected. The fonts are installed. I have to right-click and change the font properties from the font menu. The font pulldown flashes when I click on it, but I can't see or select any other fonts. Any ideas why this would suddenly happen? I use Skyfonts, but I doubt that's an issue. Thanks!

Answer (score 0):

I'm having the same issue right now.
The strange thing is, that it's only happening on "older" files.

For example, if I create a new Sketch file and type something, I can change the font face.

I'm sure, Bohemian already knows about this. But for now, a work-around is to create a new file, type something, change the font and copy the font into the other file.

I hope this helps!

Answer (score 0):

This is a bug in the newer version of Sketch. Downgrading resolves the issue...

Here you can downgrade to any version here: https://www.sketchapp.com/updates/

Answer (score 0):

The issue has been fixed in the new sketch(ver:51.1).